# Using view context in model's _post_put_hook

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I've overridden `_post_put_hook()` on one of my NDB models and I want to change the way I process my result depending on the URL the original request was made to:

```
def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    key = future.get_result()
    # Do some processing
    if <model was made thanks to POST call to /foo>:
        # Do one thing
    else:
        # Do another
```

I know this is kinda ugly and bridges the large chasm between API and underlying DB models, but nonetheless it's what I want to achieve.

I can't seem to think of a good, async-safe way to achieve this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this in (what I believe) is an async-safe way as follows:

In the view I want to have modified `_post_put_hook()` behavior for, where the future is instantiated:

```
def some_processor(self):
    ...
    future = foo.put_async()
    future.my_flag = True # Add custom flag here
    return future
```

Then in my `_post_put_hook()`:

```
def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    key = future.get_result()
    if getattr(future, 'my_flag', False):
        # Do one thing
    else:
        # Do another
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setting an 'internal' (_) attribute on the model instance as a flag, string or function for the post hook to use? The attribute field will be ignored by NDB when persisting the data.

eg:

```
class TestModel(ndb.Model):
        xyz = ndb.StringProperty()
        ...

        def _post_put_hook(self, future):
            key = future.get_result()
            # Do some processing
            try:
                fooFlag = self._fooFlag
            except:
              fooFlag = False # default if _fooFlag is not set
            if fooFlag:
                # Do one thing
            else:
                # Do another
```

eg:

```
    test = TestModel(xyz='abc', ...)
    test._fooFlag = ... #do your foo URL test here
    test.put()
```

You could also use a function instead eg

```
    test = TestModel(xyz='abc', ...)
    test._postFunc = foo if 'foo' in url else 'bar' # etc
    test.put()
```

Where 'foo' and 'bar' are normal functions.

Then:

```
def _post_put_hook(self, future):
      ...
        try:
            func = self._postFunc
        except:
            func = None # no _postFunc set
        if func is not None:
            func(self) # handle exceptions as desired
```

Regarding async safety, there shouldn't be any problem using the internal attribute (unless the same instance is used elsewhere concurrently).

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for such a detailed response! As you mention in your last sentence, this isn't technically async safe if, for example, I get two requests on the same object that I want to process differently right? I've actually just implemented another solution which, while still being a little hacky, I think solves my problem (I'll write it up soon). Thanks again